# Excel Index Match with multiple criteria and multiple results - Return first result

Tags: excel, indexing, match, formula

I am using index(match(match to find a value based on two different criteria. There are many results that will populate, I just want to return the first result. What do I need to add to my Index Match formula in order to return the first result that matches?
Below is my code and a breakdown with images:

```
=INDEX(Master_Query[Current Balance On Hand],MATCH('Waterfall 2018'!$R$1086,Master_Query[Part Number],0),MATCH($BX$1,Master_Query[Date],0))
```

Cell H1086 is were i need the result to return. I need it to match the highlighted criteria: Part Number in cell R1086 and Date in cell BX1
[image]

This is the table that we get the results from, as you can see there are many results that match the criteria in the formula, i just want to return the first one since they are all the same.
Note: The date column is filtered; there are multiple dates that will result in different "current balance on hand"(column D) results, thus I cannot use a vlookup formula. I just filtered it to make it easy to understand my problem.
[image]

Attempt 1
[image]

Attempt 1(2)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second Match looks for the column number in the index formula. So it doesn't do what you want.

One alternative is to add a column to the ELX forecast table that merges the "Date" column and the "Part number"

The formula of that column would be:

[image]

After that, in your waterfall sheet, replace your current index/match formula with:

```
=INDEX(Master_Query[Current Balance On Hand],MATCH(BX$1 & $R1086,Master_Query[Merged column],0))
```

Comment: I did exactly what you said and merged the two columns and copied your formula, but it is giving me a #N/A result

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of both screens?

Comment: I added the screen shots to the body under: Attempt 1 & Attempt 1(2), the formula for Waterfall tab is blocking the result from H1086, but it says #N/A

Comment: Recheck the merged column formula. Look at my image

Comment: Also, is the date column, a date value or text that looks like a date?

Comment: Ah, okay i see what you did there. The only problem i think will arise from this is that my table is generated from Power Query, so i executed the merge within Query editor. If i add an additional column outside Power Query won't I have to update the merged column formula by dragging down everytime the table refreshes and adds new rows of information?  Edit: the date column is a date value not a text

Comment: Formula still works even if  the data comes from power query. We need to convert the date values to their serial number.

Comment: Okay, it works now! Thank you for your help and effort, I appreciate it!